# Rewrite correlated subquery in SELECT into JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have following source table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`step` varchar(1), `cost_time` int, `rank_no` int)
;

INSERT INTO test
    (`step`, `cost_time`, `rank_no`)
VALUES
    ('a', 10, 1),
    ('b', 20, 2),
    ('c', 30, 3)
;
```

and query like this:

```
select 
  main.step,
  main.cost_time,
  main.rank_no,
  (select sum(sub.cost_time)
  from test sub
  where sub.rank_no <= main.rank_no)  as total_time
from
  test main
```

and the result is expected:

```
| step | cost_time | rank_no | total_time |
|------|-----------|---------|------------|
|    a |        10 |       1 |         10 |
|    b |        20 |       2 |         30 |
|    c |        30 |       3 |         60 |
```

is it possible to rewrite this sql using `join` statement and achieve same result?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to write this query is using a cumulative sum:

```
select main.step, main.cost_time, main.rank_no,
       sum(cost_time) over (order by rank_no) as total_time
from test main;
```

You cannot rewrite this just using `join`.  You could rewrite it using `join` and `group by`:

```
select main.step, main.cost_time, main.rank_no,
       sum(sub.cost_time) as total_time
from test main join
     test sub
     on sub.rank_no <= main.rank_no
group by main.step, main.cost_time, main.rank_no;
```

However, I think the correlated subquery is a better solution.

Comment: ( assumes 8.0+ )

Comment: window function it is, actually i'm using some platform resembles hive and window function is supported, thanks!